# Telerik Rad Editor Css not Rendring Properly

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am Using Telerik RadEditor it is working fine with Firefox and chrome but in IE it doesn't show any toolbar 
I have used the radeditor as

```
      <telerik:radeditor skinid="DefaultSetOfTools" runat="server" id="txtNotes"
                            height="250px" width="95%"  toolsfile="~/RadTool.xml">

</telerik:radeditor>
```

Snapshot of IE:

[image: IE render this editor as in below snapshot]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any js error?

Comment: No there is no any js error

Comment: Do check for handler verb.  may be you getting 404  ? or try to clear the cache

Comment: @Ravi it is working fine with other browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a maximum limit of 32 CSS file links. I have had this issue before and was solved by merging them and decreasing the number of CSS file requests.

See [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/07-05-30/all-style-tags-after-the-first-30-style-tags-on-an-html-page-are-not-applied-in-internet-explorer-workaround.aspx)

Comment: Isn't that IE7 issue? Are you getting this in IE7+?

Comment: Yes that is a browser issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that ToolsFile is loaded properly in IE and make sure that there is no nay Javascript errors in IE that might affect creation of Toolbar (You can check that using Console window of IE Developer Tools).

Refer to this Telerik Demo for [Setting Toolbars](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editortoolbars/defaultcs.aspx)